# Loading python packages when using conda enviroment with vim python-mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim, anaconda, conda

This is my first post. I hope i'm doing everything the right way.

I am running vim with python-mode and want to use it in different conda enviroments. I've included the following in my vimrc:

```
let g:pymode_python = "python3"
let g:pymode_virtualenv = 1
let g:pymode_breakpoint = 1
let g:pymode_run = 1
let g:pymode_virtualenv_path = "/my/conda/path/envs"
let g:pymode_trim_whitespaces = 1
let g:pymode_run_bind = '<leader>r'
```

I bulit vim with python3 but not python2 support and code execution is fine with standard environment and not using python-mode plugin.

Once I try to use the plugin and a conda enviroment I get the error

```
error| in <module> import netCDF4 as nc
/some/path/conda/envs/wradlib/lib/python3.6/site-packages/netCDF4/__init__.py|
3 error| in <module> from ._netCDF4 import * ImportError: 
No module named 'netCDF4._netCDF4'
```

when running the code with [python-mode](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode).

The path is correct though. Is there a way to work with conda environments and python-mode?

Thanks in advance,

Ben